# How to make a proposal for an own answer if it is not your field of expertise?

Tags: discussion

My example is simple. I asked for a variant of an algorithm I was sure it would exist. See this question:

[thinning/skeletonization algorithm with 4 known neighbors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512785/thinning-skeletonization-algorithm-with-4-known-neighbors)

Now I *think* I have a solution and I can prove it in my use cases. But I asked for an algorithm so if I answer my own question it should be an algorithm.

Now my solution is a work in progress idea of an algorithm which works in a difficult case even more interesting than a bitmap but declaring this solution as a well thought through (optimized) algorithm would be wrong. But if I post it it could be of real interest and people could participate in improving the idea.

How would you propose a solution to a question like this?

Comment: It isn't very clear to me why you can't answer your own question.  You could edit the question to make it fit the answer if necessary.  Do keep in mind that SO is not a substitute for a blog.

Comment: It's true you probably shouldn't post a "will this work" as an answer just to get feedback on if it will.  And it's also true that one should be careful of major re-writes to questions.  But in your case, no one else has attempted to answer your question yet, so how about recasting it to ask if your proposal (presented in the question body) is workable, but still leave in language that invites an alternate proposal as a possible answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I think I have a solution

- -> If no answer so far, update your question by giving details about your new approach, and formulate a precise question related to a code block or component, etc.
- -> Otherwise, edit your question, but keep it related to the provided answers, while updating it and mentioning whether some proposed answers were useful to your researches. If you don't have a specific issue at the time, it's worth mentioning it, so others don't have to try to answer your *obsolete* question (and the presence of your question on SO would be questionable, until you have something new to add)

> Now my solution is a work in progress idea of an algorithm which works
>   in a difficult case even more interesting than a bitmap but declaring
>   this solution as a well thought through (optimized) algorithm would be
>   wrong.

I don't really understand if you want to propose an algorithm or literally explain the logic behind.

- If it's an algorithm (lines of code) and no answer yet, update your question, then post your algorithm as an answer as soon as possible. However, SO is not a code project blog with tons of methods and members and classes : no real question, but a library or so is off-topic on SO (IMHO) Better (IMHO again) to delete the question, and post your findings on a code project platform.

If one or more answers has been proposed, better to select a precise issue, notify answerers you changed your mind in comments, explaining you ended up with a more elaborated code by editing your question, and post the minimal critical components of your code as your own answer (precise points where coding could be tricky for the average programmer - just post those specific portion of code)

- If it's a logic (literal, no code or just a few) perhaps SO is not the right place. Maybe [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) is more suitable.

> But if I post it it could be of real interest and people could
>   participate in improving the idea.

This assumption could apply to any question/answer on SO in a way or another. That's the purpose of Community Wiki if I understand well. But the main requirement is *"an issue + a perfect solution (if possible)"*. The way you express your question (precising the issue) and the way you include solution proposals from others define if your *question* is suitable for SO or not. This somehow requires participation from others and therefore requires you to keep others **aware** of your (new) goal. No ***real*** question = no participation = you're just sharing what you created. So the important thing on SO IMHO is not whether your code will be useful for others - ***it is**, usually* - but to clear one point : *should we participate or hold back ?*

---

One fact : If I ask a question on SO, **in the meantime**, of course I would try to find an answer or a workaround on my own, but not wait for someone else to do everything.

**But I *should* understand someone else *may also* work on my question.**

---

If no answer has been provided so far, nothing prevent you from updating your question **and sharing** what have you tried so far, helping both yourself by allowing others to give you hints per approach update, and helping others that are working on your issue to update their researches as well. I think the goal is not a race where the first to have a complete answer wins (whether it's you or someone else) but the goal is **to have the best answer possible**. (Win-Win)

IMHO, whether this approach looks like a public forum where everyone can propose, that doesn't matter while the goal (one question - best answer) is reached.

But in the first place, it must be a specific question. SO is not a blog like said above where "*I could work on a class, finalize it and post it like a code project*". That would be a very very bad move here.

And that's because the question involves **anyone** who tried **their best** to provide an answer. The minimum is to thank them (and give credit for their effort) if they post a working thing **related to the question**. If you update your question **after** other members posted answers, some answers could end off topic, and the SO topic turns garbage.

This also means that there are good and bad ways to update a question. If someone has already proposed an answer - *someone gave his time to try to help you* - it's wise to keep the **original question intact**, and notifying the update accordingly.

---

Honest opinion : if I'm trying to answer a question, I do prefer the OP gives updates on his *"research in progress"* than

- me answering, and OP commenting my answer *"ha ! already found a solution (better than yours)"* **and not even posting what he found**

or worse

- me answering, and OP never notifying whether that was helpful or not *(because he worked out a different way of solving his issue and failed or was ashamed to tell he found the solution)* - There's nothing wrong with finding the solution on your own, on the contrary, it's a very good thing, assuming you were obviously trying to find a solution to a problem.

^^ this two situations occurs sometimes (not for me so far, but I see some posts like that) IMHO, **valid** questions that doesn't have **working compliant answers** are the only *"not good question"* on SO. That's my opinion (and only mine) I know it's a severe one, but that's where I reckon the real power/importance of SO. That has nothing to do with "elite", "pride", whatever; it's a matter of accuracy, precision and efficiency : One question, one answer.